# my app has a UITextfield that must use system keyboard input, but i have no idea

Tags: ios, iphone

my app has a `UITextfield`, that must be use system number keyboard, this `UITextfield` is be used to number, can't input punctuation and alphabet,

some other input method can't limit

user can tap "返回", and keyboard change to this style [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtsaC.png)

[image]

so i must use this system keyboard [system number keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cew73.png)

[image]

I want someway, force one `ViewContoller` Or `TextField`, use system number keyboard

Comment: can you show your screen shot

Comment: Please provide little more description. A screenshot or some code. That can be really helpful your issue properly.

Comment: your textfield is used for which purpose

Comment: you can set it with the attribute inspector
`select your uitextfield` --->`go to attribute inspector` --->`Text Field` then under this, there is a field called `Keyboard Type` then set your keyboard to `Number pad`

Comment: I wouldn't rely on the keyboard type. The device may be connected to a Bluetooth keyboard, or the user may paste data into the text field. You are better off using the UITextFieldDelegate method to validate the input

Answer (score 0):

There is a `keyboardType` property for a `UITextField`:

```
typedef enum {
    UIKeyboardTypeDefault,                // Default type for the current input method.
    UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable,           // Displays a keyboard which can enter ASCII characters, non-ASCII keyboards remain active
    UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation,  // Numbers and assorted punctuation.
    UIKeyboardTypeURL,                    // A type optimized for URL entry (shows . / .com prominently).
    UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad,              // A number pad (0-9). Suitable for PIN entry.
    UIKeyboardTypePhonePad,               // A phone pad (1-9, *, 0, #, with letters under the numbers).
    UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad,           // A type optimized for entering a person's name or phone number.
    UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress,           // A type optimized for multiple email address entry (shows space @ . prominently).
    UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad,             // A number pad including a decimal point
    UIKeyboardTypeTwitter,                // Optimized for entering Twitter messages (shows # and @)
    UIKeyboardTypeWebSearch,              // Optimized for URL and search term entry (shows space and .)

    UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet = UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable, // Deprecated

} UIKeyboardType;
```

Your code should read

**Objective C**

```
 if(user is prompted for numeric input only)
            [textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];

        if(user is prompted for alphanumeric input)
            [textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDefault];
```

**Swift 2.x**

```
 if(user is prompted for numeric input only)
 textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad

if(user is prompted for alphanumeric input)
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.Default
```

Comment: This answer can't solve my question,I may not say it clearly, now I reedit my question, tks

Answer (score 0):

**In Objective-C:**

In Objective-C you can do it like this by implementing UITextfield delegate method. Textfield will only allows number to be entered.

```c
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSCharacterSet *CS = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"] invertedSet];
    NSString *filtered=[[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:CS] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    return [string isEqualToString:filtered];
}
```

**In Swift:**

```swift
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let numbersOnly = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString:"0123456789").invertedSet
    let compSepByCharInSet = string.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(numbersOnly)
    let numberFiltered = compSepByCharInSet.joinWithSeparator("")
    return string == numberFiltered
}
```